# gem rails from Github not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, gemfile

I have this in my Gemfile :

```
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails"
```

But when I do `bundle update`, it is not fetching the latest commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `github:` command is picking `master` branch, but now the official Ruby On Rails repository uses `main`

So you should write this :

```
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
```